# Is there a way to create custom animation events with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to create a custom animation event with angularJS. I am trying to create my own event of trigger an event on my own. I'd like to do the following

```
<div ng-animate="{myEvent: 'my-custom-event-handler'}"></div>
```

Anyone know if this is possible and if so do you have a link to a fiddle? an example would be very helpful. I'm guessing if this can be done it must be done with a JavaScript animation as opposed to a regular CSS3 transition animation.

Comment: Check out http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html
It's written by some of the people who build Angular's animation directives, and should cover everything you can do with it.

Comment: yeah he doesn't cover it there. But there must be some way of doing it. I have exhausted all the online docs I think. And no one has an example. I would imagine there are more than the 5 basic events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoke with the http://yearofmoo.com they say it is planned but not yet released http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html#comment-875480820 so I guess the answer is that it is coming soon.

Answer (score 3):

This is in the master branch now and it should be in 1.1.5 any day now :)
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c53d4c94300c97dd005f9a0cbdbfa387294b9026